# Query for join associations in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Campaign have attributes `:start_date,:end_date`

Invoice have attributes `:start_date,:end_date`

campaign.rb

```
has_many:invoices
```

invoice.rb

```
belongs_to:campaign
```

I want to get all those cmapaigns whose `start_date` is less than current date `AND` whose `end_date` is between `campaign.invoices.last.created..current_date`

How I query for this?

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried?

Comment: Campaign.joins(:invoices).where("campaigns.start_date < ? and campaigns.end_date > ?",Time.current,????????)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Compaign.joins(:invoices)
            .where("compaigns.start_date < :today AND compaigns.end_date < :today", today: Date.today)
            .group("compaigns.id")
            .having("compaigns.end_date > MAX(invoices.created_at)")
```

Answer (score 2):

I never used Rails magic to perform more-or-less complicated requests against database. It always results in drastic overhead, N+1 queries, or some unexpected penalties. Here is the plain old good SQL version to perform this task:

```
Campaign.connection.execute <<-SQL
   SELECT campaigns.*, last_invoice_date
   FROM campaigns 
     JOIN (
       SELECT invoices.campaign_id AS campaign_id,
              MAX(invoices.started) AS last_invoice_date
       FROM invoices
       GROUP BY invoices_campaign_id
     ) AS last_invoices
     ON (last_invoices.campaign_id = campaigns.id)
     WHERE campaigns.start_date < NOW()
       AND campaigns.end_date < NOW()
       AND campaigns.end_date >= last_invoices.last_invoice_date
SQL.to_a
```

The above was not tested for the obvious reason, but it should work either as is or with slight modifications.

Answer (score 1):

```
campaigns = Campaign.where("DATE(start_date) < ?", Date.today).includes(:invoices)

invoices = campaigns.each do |campaign|
              campaign.invoices.where("Date(campaigns.end_date)" BETWEEN campaign.invoices.last.created_at.to_date AND Date.today)
           end

invoices.map(&:campaign)
```

Comment: `campaigns.each` might take ages to execute. This is a _very_ bad practice and this is an exact example on what I meant saying “It always results in drastic overhead, N+1 queries, or some unexpected penalties.”

Comment: That's why Rails provides eager loading to avoid N+1 queries.

Comment: Oh really? Once again: `campaigns.each` from the snippet above will execute forever on, say, 1B records.

Comment: Of course for data intensive operations one has to revert to raw sql and mysql clustering.